# Can the CSS text-overflow property ellipsis be applied for vertical scrolling text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my problem. I am using Bootstrap 3. I need an element to remain 'absolute positioned' within a two column layout. My layout works great but on a tablet or mobile the design means that text scrolls underneath the 'absolute fixed element'.

If you resize the browser on a live demo you will see what I mean here: http://www.concise-courses.com/test-yourself/y/a.php

What is the work around to prevent the text scrolling underneath the clock? I was thinking a background image (didnt work) or a fading technique (didnt really work) or just text-overflow for vertical scrolling....

Any ideas? Thanks as ever!

[image: Pic of issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide `column A` when mobile, just add `hidden-xs` as a class to that column. It will hide the specified column when the screen is smaller than 768px (e.g. Bootstraps' "xs" setting, see [Bootstraps' grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more information).

**An example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LM33s/)**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm aware of the hidden class within bootstrap but I would rather not hide the element....thanks thou - appreciate you taking the time

Comment: I've decided to go with your suggestion - although not ideal it is probably the most functional. I guess on mobile we have to 'lose' some functionality. Thanks all the same H

Comment: Well yeah. I've been thinking for a better solution, but that would result in very little leftover space for column B, which wouldn't be ideal. Thanks anyway for the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

How you want it to look when its on mobile? static? or just hiding the text that behind it?

Comment: Id like to hide the text behind the timer